# get antivirus windows commandline

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I was wondering if it is possible to get the name of the currently running anti-virus within windows (xp/7/8) commandline? I could use the **tasklist** commando to view all running processes, but it would also be handy to know if it is possible to just return the name (not the full path per se) of the active anti-virus.

Comment: I am trying to gather user statistics about anti-virusscanners by running a signed java-applet which then can acces commandline to retrieve this info. I could do this by dumping the whole tasklist and then filter on all the antivirus execs but that would be a hassle

Comment: I think you'd need to identify the AV apps on your own by providing a list of known processes to your Java app representing AV apps. As far as I know, there is no API within Windows for this purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using an anti-virus package that properly reports into Windows' Security Centre you should be able to get its name via WMI.

This will return a list of all installed AV products from the local machine:

`WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:List`

Note: I only tested this on Windows 7, so I'm not sure if it will work on XP as-is (should work on Vista+ though).

Comment: thank you :) I know wmic for a while, but didn't know this was also possible. ( i mostly use wmic to uninstall things)

Comment: @Techie007, How to get exluded files list aslo.